# What packages do these come from?

Tags: acronyms

Just wondering if anyone could tell me the packages I need to call in order to use the following commands, `\notat` and `\acron`? Two examples of the code in use are shown below.

These are used for notation and acronyms respectively. I've seem them used but can't seem to track down the package.

```
\acron{CAD}{Computer Aided Design}
\notat{h}{Height}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where have you seen them?

Comment: I don't know any package. Please search your template document for `\newcommand{\acron}` or `\newcommand{\notat}` as they may be custom defined.

Comment: You can find some other usages by googling for e.g. `latex "\notat"`, but it doesn't appear to be any well known package that defines them.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the responses (i've been a bit slow in replying) but I found the code that he used. @LaRiFaRi, you were right, it was custom defined, just had to search deep for it.

```
%New Commands: acronyms and notations - Notations are amsmath
\usepackage{tabto}
\newcommand{\acron}[2]{\textbf{#1}\tabto{8em}#2\\}
\newcommand{\notat}[2]{\textbf{\(#1\)}\tabto{8em}#2\\}
```